# Convert Python UTC time stamp to local time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, utc

Im trying to convert a UTC timestamp generated with python to connecting clients local time. But, the time never converts correctly.

**Python**

```
import time, datetime


utc_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
utc_time = int(time.mktime(utc_time.timetuple())) * 1000
```

**JavaScript**

```
function Time(time) {
    var month = {}
    month[0] = "Jan";
    month[1] = "Feb";
    month[2] = "Mar";
    month[3] = "Apr";
    month[4] = "May";
    month[5] = "Jun";
    month[6] = "Jul";
    month[7] = "Aug";
    month[8] = "Sept";
    month[9] = "Oct";
    month[10] = "Nov";
    month[11] = "Dec";
    day = {}
    day[0] = "Sunday";
    day[1] = "Monday";
    day[2] = "Tuesday";
    day[3] = "Wednesday";
    day[4] = "Thursday";
    day[5] = "Friday";
    day[6] = "Saturday";
    var b = new Date();
    var d = new Date(time);
    var c = d.getTime() + (b.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    var offset = -(b.getTimezoneOffset() /60);
    var res = c + (3600000 * offset);
    d.setTime(res);
    var days = day[d.getDay()];
    var mon = d.getMonth();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var hour = d.getHours();
    var minute = d.getMinutes();
    var seconds = d.getSeconds();
    var date = d.getDate();
    return days + ' - ' + month[mon] + '/' + date + '/' + year + " - " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + seconds;
}
console.log(Time(1429490580*1000)); 
// time stamp generated: Sunday - Apr/19/2015  at 4:43PM
```

Is my math wrong or is it something I did wrong on the python side?

Comment: what python version?

Comment: the python version is 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You timestamp is incorrect:

```
import datetime
utc_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
timestamp = (utc_time - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript seems much more complicated than necessary, unless I'm misunderstanding your goal. Unix timestamp values are always UTC, and the base Date.toString() will output in the local client timezone by default. Manual conversion shouldn't be necessary unless you want an output format other than the standard ones provided.

```
var ourDateTime = new Date(timestampFromServer);
console.log(ourDateTime.toString());
```

Comment: I did what you posted and  I get `Sun Apr 19 2015 20:43:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)` the time is off by 4 hours

Comment: What was the timestamp produced by the server, and what date were you expecting? That time string matches 1429490580000.

Comment: `1429490580000` should match `Sunday - Apr/19/2015  at 16:43` that's when that particular value was generated.

Comment: As I'm posting this, the current Unix timestamp is 1429483975000. I think your generation of the timestamp on the server is off.